# build.phonegap app. Cant scroll with finger on iPhone (requires 2 fingers)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build

I have built an app using build.phonegap.com (phonegap version 3.6.3). While testing the app on devices I am unable to scroll vertically on my iphone with a single finger, it requires 2 fingers to scroll. However on ipad I am able to scroll on 1.

This is my viewport meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered: It was because I had height: 100%; on the div I wanted to scroll!